# How to get 00h over/below 23h when ordering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Having this dataframe, what I would is to have the rows that have the `start_time` with 00:XX:XX at the top (descending for example)

[image]

PS: `start_time` comes from `df['start].dt.time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact ordering, use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and possibly [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

- ### `00h`, `01h`, ..., `23h`

  Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) which is ascending by default:

  ```
  df = df.sort_values('start_time')
  ```
- ### `23h`, `22h`, ..., `00h`

  Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `ascending=False`:

  ```
  df = df.sort_values('start_time', ascending=False)
  ```
- ### `00h`, `23h`, `22h`, ..., `01h`

  Use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to change `00:##:##` into `24:##:##`, then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `ascending=False`, then change `24:##:##` back to `00:##:##`:

  ```
  df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].str.replace(r'^00(:\d{2}:\d{2})', r'24\1', regex=True)
  df = df.sort_values('start_time', ascending=False)
  df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].str.replace(r'^24(:\d{2}:\d{2})', r'00\1', regex=True)
  ```